# how to select zero index array value in react native,

Tags: react-native

```
let get_plans= this.state.get_dietplans;
return render(
  {(get_plans.length > 0 ) && get_plans.map(
    (data, index) => {
      return( <Text>{data.name}</Text> )
     })
  })
)
```

this is my sample code , but I don't know how to select individual data in array

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "select" individual data or "zero index array"?

If you want to do something when an item from an array is "clicked", you can do something like this.

```
let get_plans= this.state.get_dietplans;

const selectedNthIndexDietPlan = (i: number, data: any) => {
  // Do sth with it
  console.log(`Selected ${i}-th item!`)
}

return render(
  {(get_plans.length > 0 ) && get_plans.map(
    (data, index) => {
      return( 
        <Pressable onPress={() => {selectedNthIndexDietPlan(index, data)}}>
          <Text>{data.name}</Text>
        </Pressable> 
      )
     })
  })
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "select" individual data or "zero index array"?  it means I want to  select induvial data by using array index value and display. like data[0].name data[2].name